# TSQL - How to return 2 values with one case statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008, case-statement

Is there a way to use one [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement and return 2 different values?

Following query has 2 `CASE` statements with same conditions.

```
select  case when DA.value = 1 
            then da.Good else da.Bad end as Foo,
        case when DA.value = 1 
            then ot.Good else ot.Bad end as Bar,
from    someTable DA (nolock)
        join otherTable OT (nolock) on OT...
where   ...
```

Is there anyway, to specify that `CASE` statement ***once***? 
so that there is no need to keep both `CASE` statements in sync whenever the condition changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do what you're describing.  Not only is your case statement different for both cases, but you're returning values from totally different tables in each case.

Comment: @Josheph.  Thank you for the answer.  This question was mainly to confirm whether there is actually a way to do so.  But I was not able to find a way around it even after reading MSDN BOL.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you need, but you can do combinations like:

```
select
   case
      when da.value = 1 and ot.attributeValue = 1 then ot.good
      when da.value = 2 and ot.attributeValue = 3 then ot.good
      ...
      else ot.bad
   end Result
from
   someTable DA

   JOIN otherTable OT
      on (ot.id = da.id)
```